# Associating functions to terms with fictitious arguments

Tags: logic, reference-request

This is somewhat related to a previous question I asked on how to associate functions to terms. Suppose, just for this example at least, that our language is $(+,-,*,0,1)$, whose interpretations are in $\mathbb{R}$. We also have a set of variables indexed by the positive integers. How does one associate functions to terms with fictitious arguments? For example, consider the term $(0*x_2)+x_1+1$ Should that be a function on $\mathbb{R}^2$, or on $\mathbb{R}$, since its second argument is fictitious? And what about something like, say, $(0*x_1)+x_2+(0*x_3)$? Should that be a function on $\mathbb{R}^3$, or on $\mathbb{R}^2$, since the second argument is the last that is non-fictitious? I apologize if this is too pedantic, but I am just really interested in these foundational matters. Also, is there a book or text where this is very precisely defined?

Edit: One of the main reasons I asked this question, is because if you simplify certain terms, it can lead to a different domain of the function of the associated term. Like, for example, simplifying $(0*x_2)+x_1+1$ to $x_1+1$.

Comment: also if the "second argument is fictitious", $(0∗x_2)+x_1+1$ is a function of two variables: $x_1$ and $x_2$. The fact that $x_2$ multiplied by zero outputs zero is "formally" irrelevant. The function $\text {zero}(x)=0$ for every $x$ is a well-defined function-

Comment: I can't think of a single situation in which we'd want to perform this sort of simplification. Part of this has to do with universality: while (for example) $x_2$ is irrelevant in "$x_1+(0\cdot x_2)$" in the particular structure $\mathbb{R}$, this is not the case across **all** structures in the appropriate language. A term describes a way to assign to each structure a function on that structure; "simplifying" expressions in a structure-dependent way ruins the uniformity of this process (e.g. sometimes we get a unary function, sometimes we get a binary function, all from the same term).

Comment: @NoahSchweber But I am in fact talking about a particular structure.

Comment: @user107952 But one of the points of model theory is that even when we're talking about a single structure, there's no reason to adopt language which will prevent us from easily passing to other similar structures. There's no advantage to doing the sort of simplification you're describing, so why do it?

Comment: @NoahSchweber A motivation for me asking this question is because a friend of mine and I were arguing whether 0y + x +1 is in fact the same function as x + 1 over the reals, or merely "equivalent" functions. (I have relabeled, in my body question, x as x_1 and y as x_2). Anyway, I am still interested in simplification in particular structures, and this notion of "equivalence".